# createjs fileload event with registerSound

Tags: backbone.js, createjs

I am using this CDN version of createjs

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.min.js"></script>
```

as I'm trying to follow along with this introductory screencast http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWHJa0jKJgo on Youtube. It has a line

```
 createjs.Sound.addEventListener("loadComplete", this.handleComplete);
```

However, "loadComplete" was deprecated recently and replaced by a "fileLoad" event. If I do this inside a function in a Backbone View

```
  loadRegisterSound: function(){
  createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", this.handleLoad);
  createjs.Sound.registerSound("img/pop.mp3", "sound");
  }
```

then I get this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleEvent' of undefined
```

If I move the second half of the above function into the handleLoad function

```
loadRegisterSound: function(){
      createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", this.handleLoad);

      },

handleLoad: function(){
   createjs.Sound.registerSound("img/pop.mp3", "sound");
   var ball = new createjs.Shape();
   ball.graphics.beginFill("#000000").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
   createjs.Tween.get(ball, {loop:true}).to({x:450}, 3000).to({x:50}, 3000);
   createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.tick);
   ball.addEventListener("click", this.handleClick);

   ball.x = 50;
   ball.y = 200;
   stage.addChild(ball);
}
```

then there's no indication of the handleLoad function ever getting called. Nothing happens.

In the docs for createjs http://www.createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/classes/Sound.html, there's a strange createjs.proxy function used with the fileload event

```
 createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", createjs.proxy(this.loadHandler, (this));
```

However, if I try to use it with my code in a Backbone View, I get an unexpected `;` error.

Can someone explain how I could get the `fileload` event to work together with createjs.registerSound api?

Answer (score 1):

createjs.proxy is used to maintain scope, so when the handler function is called it will be called in the correct context of the object or library it exists in.  Scope in javascript is a complex topic and worth reading more about if you are unfamiliar with it.

I'm confused by your code snippet above, as it appears you are loading a sound from an image folder, and after the load you create a shape and add it to the stage.
Using your code, I think this is what you want to play a sound:

```
createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", createjs.proxy(this.handleLoad, this));
createjs.Sound.registerSound("img/pop.mp3", "sound");
function handleLoad(event) {
  var instance = createjs.Sound.play("sound");
}
```

Drawing shapes to the stage is not related to loading and playing sound, and it might make sense to separate the code as well.  The screencast is a out of date now, but you can find useful official tutorials on the [createjs site](http://www.createjs.com/) that can help you get started, as well as simple examples.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Note that the latest version of createjs includes an `on()` method, which is a handy shortcut for `addEventListener`, including a `scope` parameter.